# How to use a method provided by active_support outside of rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I use a method that is defined in `ActiveSupport` module?

For example I wanted to use `camelize` method.

I tried this code, but it didn't work with `undefined method` error.

```
require 'active_support'
"foo_bar".camelize
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can require just the part that supplies camelize, rather than *all* of Active Support:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string'
"camel_this".camelize => "CamelThis"
```

Comment: Or even just `require 'active_support/core_ext/string/inflections'`.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to do `require 'active_support/all'`

This explains it...

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html

Comment: Note that this may give you more than you want. I think explicitly opting for the stuff you really *need* is preferable in this case.